Trouble deploying Astro website to Github pages due to components, layout, configuration?
When I try to deploy my astro website on Github pages, I get an error with finding the modules related to my components and layout. When I run the site locally, everything renders in just fine.

My github is repo is https://github.com/rainer27/rainer27.github.io
I tried changing the directory paths from the .. to ~ but no luck.

can you reproduce locally with npm run build? or try opening in VSCode and have it fix the imports. Finally, make sure all your files are commited to git.
